# Where save uploaded avatar

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, avatar

I can't find a response to my question.

I'm building a React app using NodeJS and CRA and i need to implement an uploading avatar system. But i'm not sure where to save the uploaded image. My Node server serve a static folder 'public', so does i need to save images in /public/avatar? But each time i will make update on the app and re-build the client-side folder, this will overwrite the public folder and remove all the previous uploaded avatar ?  I'm right ? So what are you suggesting me ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple locations that you can store your user uploaded images, though storing them in your public is probably not the best location.

In the case where you were using a database like MongoDB, you could store the image inside Mongo using [gridfs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) and serve the data using a route when you retrieve the user information. Similarly, you can also store in the database a path to the file, and return the path, or the file data, from the route as well.

Be careful with user uploads, however, as arbitrarily allowing uploaded data can lead to unanticipated results if you're not careful.

Comment: Thank you for your response CoolestNerdlll.

Yes i'm using MongoDB to save some data, but in the case  i implement a chat where avatar are displayed i can't make a request to retrieve all  avatars each time a new user is talking, i thinks it's not a really good and efficient way ?

Comment: If you are going to show the user's name, details, or anything about the user, the request/response that returns that information can very easily also include the data of the image or the path to image.

Comment: Hum, ok perfect i see now how to implement that . Thanks a lot. Have a good day

Comment: Hopefully this at least points you in a good direction. You can also look at caching the image/data to limit the requests too.

Comment: Yes, i will try to get more information about that. I think there is some package that offer this feature. Maybe i have to check the uploaded image if there is no malware behind ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Gravatar (https://gravatar.com/).
User can choose an avatar assigned to their mail address hash, or use an automatically generated one by default.

Though with this solution you cannot let users change their avatar directly on your website.

It is widely used on well known websites like StackOverflow.

Comment: Yeah i've read about their services, but i'm not really a good fan. I think's 
it's a bit too untrusive